# Creating a Notepad- Windows forms

Tags: windows, forms

New in the business. Iam creating a windows form Notepad. How do I do the Button Open to open a file and a specific compatible file?

Answer (score 0):

KInd off. I am creating a Notepad with Visual Studio. In the Menu strip, I created a buttion save and another open. De form design its ok, now I need to lear the code c#, to put in the event "Open file" in the notepad that  I am creating.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public MeuBloco()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void guardarToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

    }

    private void SalvarOK(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        string caminho = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
        File.WriteAllText(caminho, txbJanela.Text);
    }

    private void abrirToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void OpenOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

// Now I need to code the event to open the file I want.